# C Language: Scanning and printing Names

Tags: c, arrays, scanf

Today, i written a C Programe to scan Two names from keyboard and print it on monitor here it is

```
char b[2],i;

for(i=0;i<2;i++)
{
    scanf("%s",b[i]);
}
for(i=0;i<2;i++)
{
    printf("%s",b[i]);
}
```

But Output is runtime Error, I am a Beginner to C. What  should i do to make it proper program.

Comment: What compiler are you using? I'm surprised it isn't giving you warnings about this.

Comment: I am using a online compiler,

Comment: http://beginnersbook.com/2014/01/c-arrays-example/

Comment: Also keep in mind that `scanf()` needs an address for a destination.

Comment: And, why is `i` a `char`? Make it an `int`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See what you have declared is wrong char `b[2]`. You are scanning string values and your **declaration says that you want two characters in b array**
If you want to accept two string value than your declaration must be:

```
char *b[1];
```

Here you can scan the value in the array as:

```
*b[0] = "string1";
*b[1] = "string2";
```

**OR**
You can use two dimensional array for the storage and then your declaratoin would be:

```
char b[2][100];
```

Now here, the 100 specifies the number of characters the string you want to enter and 2 is the number of values of the string you are entering.
I hope this will clear your doubts.

Comment: @CoolGuy He is beginner and I have told him the right method for declaration. Later on he will study it. What problem he is facing now is what I have mentioned in my answer. I think for a beginner this is the right solution. I think this is why you have downvoted me. Instead of giving the right answer...

Comment: I agree that the OP is just a beginner. That means that the OP will just substitute `char b[2]` with `char *b[2];`. This will lead to problems especially if it happens to "work" as expected for the OP as the pointers are uninitialized and are pointing to some memory location. So, you should mention about initializing those pointers before scanning into them. As for your second suggestion, `char b[100][2];` should be `char b[2][100];`

Comment: @CoolGuy ok thank you .. Now I understood.. I will make corrections. I have edited and thanks again.

Comment: I'm sorry, but `*b[0] = "string1";
*b[1] = "string2";` doesn't make any sense (Take a look at the compiler warnings). And by scanning, the OP wanted to take input from the user (via `scanf("%s",b[i])`), not assigning a string literal. And you aren't supposed to use `b[1];` if you have an array of size 1 declared like `char *b[1];`.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, `%s` is to intake *strings*, `%c` is meant to scan individual characters.

That said, in your case,

1. You did not allocate the spacer for null-terminator in the array.
2. you did not null-terminate the input, either. So even if you want, it cannot be used as a *sting*.

Comment: could you post complete programme?

Comment: @RAM what complete program? You write it, we'll help.

Comment: how to allocate null character in array ? like this b[2]={\0}?

Comment: The OP wants to scan strings, not characters. Also, you should mention about using `&` in `scanf` in your current answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can correct your code as per given below so that you get correct output.

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{
    char b[2][20];
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<2;i++)
    {
            scanf("%s",b[i]);
    }
    for(i=0;i<2;i++)
    {
            printf("%s\n",b[i]);
    }
}
```